# Generate tubes with non-circular cross-sections in MuPad

Tags: matlab, mupad

Using `plot::tube` function in MuPAD, I can generate tubes with varying spine but the cross-section is always a circle, although the radius can vary along the spine. For instance:

```
plot::Tube([cos(t), sin(t), 0], 0.4 + 0.3*sin(t)*cos(t),t = -0.5*PI..0.5*PI,Mesh=[60,12]):
```

I want to plot tubes with (non-circular) elliptical cross-sections. Is there a way to achieve this in MuPAD?

P.S. I can generate tubes with arbitrary cross-sections using MATLAV, so please avoid including answers that use pure MATLAB commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your first question whether this can be done with `plot::Tube`: I don't think so. Consider the help of this function (emphasis mine):

> `plot::Tube` creates generalized tubular plots, known as "canal
>   surfaces", with special cases known as "tube surface", "pipe surface"
>   or "tubular surfaces."
>
> Intuitively, canal surfaces are space curves with thickness. More formally, a canal surface `plot::Tube([x(t), y(t), z(t)], r(t), t = t_min..t_max)` is **the envelope of spheres** with center `[x(t), y(t), z(t)]` and radius `r(t)`, i.e., the thickness of the curve can vary with
>   the curve parameter `t`

The fact that a tube is defined as an envelope of a collection of spheres suggests that their cross-section is inherently circular.

I'm not familiar with MuPAD, so I don't know the *elegant* solution to your problem. For your simple example of a semi-circular base line I could put together this kludgy solution using the low-level `plot::Surface`, manually constructing the surface:

```
plot(
  plot::Surface(
      matrix([cos(t),sin(t),0]) 
      + numeric::rotationMatrix(t,[0,0,1]) * matrix([(0.2+0.1*sin(2*t))*cos(u),0,(0.2+0.1*cos(2*t))*sin(u)]),
      t = -PI/2..PI/2,
      u = 0..2*PI,
      Mesh = [30,30]),
  Scaling=Constrained)
```

[image: output]

Here `t` stands for the angular parameter along the semi-circular base line (toroidal direction), and `u` is the angle along the cross-section (poloidal direction). A given cross-section at angle `t` looks like this:

```
[(0.2+0.1*sin(2*t))*cos(u), 0, (0.2+0.1*cos(2*t))*sin(u)]
```

I.e. the semimajor axes are `(0.2+0.1*sin(2*t))` and `(0.2+0.1*cos(2*t))` along the cross-section of the tube.

You can see that I used a rotation matrix around the `z` axis to construct the surface. This made heavy use of the fact that the base line is a semi-circle. However, in general cases it should be possible to compute the derivative of your parameterized base line (with respect to `t`), and compute the necessary rotation angle (with parameter `t`) from that.

Comment: That's awesome! thank you. I can work out the arbitrary cross-sections now.